# functional version of std::transform

Tags: c++

When applying a function to a collection of elements, `std::transform` takes the output as 3rd parameter. Is there version which returns the result, something like `vec2 = map(func, vec1)`?

Comment: How would that function know what to return? The closest you'd get is probably a `transform_iterator`, see i.e. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that in the standard library. You can write one yourself:

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
std::vector<T> transform(std::vector<T> const &input, Func func) {
    std::vector<T> result(input.size());
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), result.begin(), func);
    return result;
}
```

A better solution may be to use [`transformed` adaptor from Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) as it does not allocate additional container.